# JS closure to return object instance as interface

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have the following code.

```
function Test() {
this.funct_1 = function() {
    alert('funct_1');
}

this.funct_2 = function() {
    alert('funct_2');
}
return this;}
```

---

```
function getTestObj() {
var testObj;
if (!testObj) {
    testObj = new Test();
}
return function() {
    return testObj;
}}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following. I want to have a class `Test` which is not singleton. Then in some other places in my application I need to have a function  which could return the same instance per script execution. I figured that I could use closure for that `getTestObj`.

However, when I try to use it

```
getTestObj().funct_1();
```

I'm getting the following error, saying the `funct_1()` is not found.

*Cannot find function funct_1 in object function () {...}.*

Clearly, I'm making some kind of mistake here, but I'm not able to find any solution over the net which could help me. Would appreciate any comments.

NOTE: I'm forced to use ECMA5

Comment: @gurvinder372 In this case each time I call `getTestObj()` I would get a new instance of `Test` but I need only one instance per script execution. Also, I cannot expose any `var` outside the `getTestObj()`

Comment: getTestObj is returning function so you have to call it as getTestObj()()
this will return Test class's object.
So answer is : getTestObj()().funct_1()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`testObj` is wrapped inside a `function`**

So, either call it

```
getTestObj()().funct_1(); //notice two ()()
```

Save the value of `getTestObj()` in a variable

```
var singleTon = getTestObj();
var testObj = singleTon();
testObj.funct_1();
```

Or, simply `return testObj` (in case singleTon isn't required)

```
function getTestObj() 
{
   var testObj;
   if (!testObj) {
      testObj = new Test();
   }
   return testObj;
}
```

And invoke it as

```
getTestObj().funct_1(); //notice single ()
```

Comment: with simply returning `return testObj` I will get a new instance each time I call `getTestObj()` however I need the same instance per script execution. With double `()()` I guess it's a solution however could it be avoided? I mean redesign it somehow to don't have the double `()()`

Comment: @blisss05 I have updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! One thing that I cannot expose any `var` outside the `getTestObj()` and it should be as only entry to get the `Test` instance.

Comment: @blisss05 You don't have to, only `var singleTon` is declared and initialized outside.

Comment: Ok, I see. However, Is there any approach to don't use any additional `var` instances and use only closure here ?

Comment: You need to save the reference to the `singleTon` somewhere or else you need to invoke `getTestObj()()` which will create a new Object.

Answer (score 0):

getTestObj() is returning a function i.e. :

```
function() {
return testObj;
}
```

So you have to call it again getTestObj()(), this will return the Test's object and now you can access it's properties.

```
getTestObj()().funct_1();
```

OR

You can change your getTestObj function as :

```
function getTestObj() {
  var testObj;
  if (!testObj) {
     testObj = new Test();
  }
  return (function() {
        return testObj;
  }());
 }
```